# Mobile Email Client with exposed API

Tags: android, mobile, email-client

Is there a mobile email client app for android/iOs that exposes a set of API for use by another mobile app on same device?

For example, there is an app on android device that needs to find all emails received from a certain email address and then display a summary list. This could be possible, if an email client app on the same device allows search through some API.